# How to get text from jtextfield and skip to jtable row based on text?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield

I have 1 column with 100 names, all from A to Z. I have to choose 1. I want to be able to insert a few letters into a jtextfield, press enter, and have the row be selected that matches the text. How do I do this?

An example would be, I type "Bro", press enter and the selection skips to the first name that starts with "Bro". I dont mean a filter, I want to skip to it.

Answer (score 1):

> I have 1 column

So why are you using a JTable? Why not use a JList?

> I want to be able to insert a few letters into a jtextfield, press enter,

You can do the search as every letter is typed (or removed), instead of forcing the user to press Enter.

1. Create a JTextField for entering the name to search for:
2. Add a DocumentListener to the Document of the text field. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Listening For Changes on a Document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) for the basics.
3. In the `DocumentListener` you would get the model of your `JList` (or `JTable`) and then iterate through each item in the model to find the index of the first item that starts with the text in the text field.
4. If you use a `JList` then you just use the `setSelectedIndex(...)` methodto select the row and the `ensureIndexIsVisible(...)` method to scroll to the row
5. if you use a `JTable` then you use the `changeSelection(...)` method to select the row and then the `scrollRectToVisible(...)` method to scroll to the row using data from the `getCellRect(...)` method.